# Не отображается логотип по центру

Tags: html

Столкнулся с тем, что не отображает логотип по середине страницы, хотя все прописано, все картинки все присутствует

```css
.header {
  min-height: 85vh;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: box-shadow 0.3s ease;
}
#backgroundVideo {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
  filter: brightness(50%); /* Затемнение видео, значение от 0% до 100% */
}
.logo-container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  z-index: 1209;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.logo {
  width: 100%;
}
button {
  border: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background: transparent;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.navbar,
.navbar-burger,
.menu {
  position: fixed;
}
body.open .background {
  filter: blur(10px);
}
.navbar {
  z-index: 1201;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  width: 100%;
  height: 72px;
  padding-left: 20px;
  padding-right: 72px;
}

.navbar-burger {
  z-index: 1203;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
  width: 88px;
  height: 88px;
  background-image: url("./assets/menu.svg");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
}

body.open .navbar-burger {
  background-image: url("./assets/close.svg");
}

.menu {
  z-index: 1200;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  border-bottom: 20px solid white;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

body.open .menu {
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
}

.menu nav:hover a {
  opacity: 0.25;
}

.menu nav a:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}

.menu nav {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.menu a {
  position: relative;
  color: #f9f9f9;
  font-size: 32px;
  padding: 20px 0;
  width: 300px;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: 0.4s;
}

.menu a::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 10px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 2px;
  border-radius: 2px;
  background: #f7f7f7;
  transform: scaleX(0);
  transform-origin: 0% 50%;
  transition: 0.4s;
}

.menu a:hover::after {
  transform: scaleX(1);
}

body.open .menu a {
  animation: appear 0.3s backwards;
}

@keyframes appear {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    translate: 0 50px;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
.icon {
  display: block;
  font-size: 30px;
  line-height: 70px;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #fff;
}
@media (max-width: 700px) {
  .header {
    min-height: 70vh;
  }
  .text-box h1 {
    font-size: 14px;
  }
}
.text-box {
    width: 100%;
    color: #f7f7f7;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
    text-align: center;
}
.text-box h1{
    font-size: 80px;
    color: #ffffff;
    font-weight: 600;
}
.text-box h1 span {
  color: #6f53ed;
  position: relative;
}
.text-box h1 span::before {
  content: "";
  height: 50px;
  width: 2px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  right: -8px;
  background: #6f53ed;
  transform: translateY(-45%);
  animation: blink 0.7s infinite;
}
.textbox h1 span.stop-blinking::before {
  animation: none;
}
@keyframes blink {
  50% { opacity: 0 }
}

.text-box p{
    margin: 10px 0 40px;
    font-size: 15px;
    color: #a8a8a8;
}
.hero-btn{
    display: inline-block;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #fcfcfc;
    border: 1px solid #ffffff0e;
    border-radius: 5px;
    padding: 12px 34px;
    font-size: 14px;
    background: none;
    position: relative;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: 0.8s;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.hero-btn:hover{
    background: #524FD5;
}
.hero-btn::before{
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 0%;
    background: #524FD5;
    z-index: -1;
    transition: 0.7s;
    bottom: 0;
    border-radius: 50% 50% 0 0;
}
.hero-btn:hover::before{
    height: 180%;
}
```

```html
    <section class="header">
      <video autoplay muted loop id="backgroundVideo">
        <source src="images/backgroundvideo.mp4" type="video/mp4">
        Your browser does not support the video tag.
      </video>
      <div class="logo-container">
        <a href="index.html">
          <img src="images/logocolor.png" alt="Logo" class="logo">
        </a>
      </div>
      <button class="navbar-burger" onclick="toggleMenu()"></button>
      <div class="menu">
        <nav>
          <a href="#" style="animation-delay: 0.1s">About</a>
          <a href="#" style="animation-delay: 0.2s">Portfolio</a>
          <a href="#" style="animation-delay: 0.3s">Services</a>
          <a href="#" style="animation-delay: 0.5s">Contact</a>
        </nav>
      </div>
      <script type="text/javascript">
        const toggleMenu = () => {
          document.body.classList.toggle("open");
        };
      </script>
      <div class="text-box">
        <h1>HARMONY OF <span></span></h1>
        <p>Уникальная программа обучения для вашего ребенка.<br>Получите качественное международное образование уже сейчас.</p>
        <a href="" class="hero-btn">ПОЛУЧИТЬ КОНСУЛЬТАЦИЮ</a>
      </div>
    </section>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
   .logo-container {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100vh;//<==
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
        z-index: 1209;
        margin: 0 auto;
  }
```